# firebug is erroniously telling me my variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, firebug

I'm setting a breakpoint in the code below where it says "breakpoint". Also adding a watch expression for dataStore.

```
function(){
  var self = {};
  var dataStore = [];
  var areEq = UNAB.objectsAreEqual;

  self.put = function(key, value){
    /*breakpoint*/ dataStore.push({key:key, value:value});
  }
  return self;
}
```

At this breakpoint, Firebug tells me "ReferenceError: dataStore is not defined". Same results with trying to examine "areEq". However, dataStore.push executes without error. An additional strangness: adding a watch expression for "self" shows not the self object I expect, with one property, "put", but the "window" object.

Any idea what the heck is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a firefox bug. If you set a breakpoint on 
  var dataStore = [];
then continue, when hit the breakpoint in put(). you get a closure scope (in Firebug 1.6). That scope has dataStore and self.  I think Firefox is optimizing the closure scope away, perhaps since the code is nonsense anyway: there is no way to access dataStore.

A complete test case will eventually appear at 
http://getfirebug.com/tests/script/stackoverflow/dataStoreIsNotDefined.html

see also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.self

Comment: Thanks for confirming that I'm not crazy (at least not in this particular way). And thanks for reporting the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `self` is getting resolved by Firebug and probably also by Firefox in the global scope as referring to the current window. If you choose a different name other than "self", your code should make everyone happy.

Comment: You're correct. `window.self` is the same as `window`. The OP's code itself is perfectly correct JavaScript and will execute without error, but it seems the Firebug debugger somehow has the wrong context when it breaks.

Comment: I've been creating "classes", using var self-{} for over a year, many dozens of times, and never had a problem with self. I'll try something else though. Thanks!

Comment: I replaced "self" with "_this", and get the same behavior. Annoying! Weird!